# Samsung Galaxy Young GT-S5360 has Android 7 but Api 10 using custom rom

Tags: samsung, custom-roms, 7.0-nougat

I have installed android 7 successfully using a custom rom and wanted to install some apps but noticed that most apps needed an api higher than 10. The weird thing is that android 7 normally has api 24. For some reason it still has my android 2.3.2 api version (10). Is there anyway to increase or update this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you link the ROM and the app you want to install? Browsing [XDA](https://xdaforums.com/f/galaxy-y-gt-s5360-android-development.1472/), I only found Android 4.4.4 KitKat as the latest version. There's also CyanogenMod (CM) 7, which is actually based on Android 2.3.6, not Android 7.0.

Comment: Hi, I had android 7 but now im going to download 4.4.4 kitkat since its the actual latest version like you stated. I was checking the ro.build.version.sdk inside of build.prop to check if its the actual android. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi can you help me on which files and/or tutorials I should follow to install kitkat?

Comment: The tutorial should be similar for flashing any custom ROM. You can pick one listed in the XDA Forum. They usually include the installation steps.

Comment: I think I bricked it D: I cant boot into recovery and its stuck on the Samsung galaxy y logo.